# Fazer logout no SOPT

Tags: suporte, login

Sei que é uma pergunta simples mas não consigo achar em nenhum lugar no site do SOPT uma área para logout.

Onde faço logout?

Comment: Olá @pnet! Bem-vindo ao *Meta* do StackOverflow em Português! Notou o prefixo `meta.` na URL? Pois então, aqui é o lugar onde discutimos coisas **sobre o site principal**. Você pode usar esse espaço justamente para sanar suas dúvidas sobre o uso do site, sobre possíveis *bugs* que vier a encontrar ou mesmo para debater sobre alguma pergunta ou assunto do site principal. Tenho visto que você tem melhorado bastante ao usar o site. Dê uma passada pelo meta de vez em quando. Vai ajudar você a entender melhor o comportamento da comunidade.

Comment: Valeu utluiz. Vou sim, fazer ao meta visitas esporádicas sim. Eu preciso mesmo ir entendendo o site.

Comment: Apenas um conselho... Quando não souber onde fazer o logout de um site, não apenas o SOPT, mas qualquer outro, lembre-se que o login geralmente é realizado por cookies, e que você pode "simplesmente" apagar todos os cookies do navegador...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

<s>O link do logout está na barra da stack exchange(no canto superior esquerdo) depois dos link bate-papo e blog</s>

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

### Atualizado 09/2019

A barra mudou a algum tempo, a localização do log-out agora fica no menu no canto superior direito, conforme imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cara, já vi essa parte do site e confesso, sem brincadeiras, não vi o logout, tanto é que na última empresa em que saí de lá, deixei o SOPT logado por não saber onde deslogar. Como eles sempre formatam a máquina para outra pessoa, fiquei tranquilo.

Comment: Mude sua senha para evitar qualquer dúvida.